# Java replaceAll(..) and Regular Expressions

Tags: java, regex, string, replaceall

How can I delete a text with parentheses?

```
String string = "product(version(id),code),user(uid)";
string = string.replaceAll("\\(.*\\)", "");
System.out.println("string= " + string);
```

When I do this, I get:

```
string= product
```

But I would like get

```
string= product,user
```

Best regards!

Comment: Re-closed with a more appropriate dupe. Also, see a demo - https://ideone.com/Hq8BeZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
String string = "(product(version(id),code),use)r(uid)";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int countOpenPar = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<string.length(); i++) {
      char c = string.charAt(i);

      if( c == '(' ){
        countOpenPar++;
      }else if( c == ')' ){
        countOpenPar-- ;
      }else if( countOpenPar == 0){
        sb.append(c);
      }
    }
    System.out.println("string= " + sb.toString());
```